# curl login and browse the rest of the site

Tags: php, curl

So, I am creating a script that will automatically logging in the user to a remote site. it's work as expected, but when user browse any pages in the remote site, it's keep asking user to login again.

how to prevent this? is this possible to do so? here is the current code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER=>false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true,
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$login,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>$rootPath.'/tmpfile/cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=>$rootPath.'/tmpfile/cookie.txt'
));

$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems workable. But most of the cases the common mistake is not closing the curl handle before making second one. So close it, and reinitialize it again.

```
curl_close($ch);
```

If this still doesn't solve your problem, then you can debug your code for following things.

1) Check what you have inside the cookie.txt file. You can print the content of the file just after the login request.

2) Run the script with verbose mode enabled to see what requests are sending for user browsing pages.

```
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
```

3) You can also manually copy the cookie from the file (or from browser) and use it for the 'user browse' request and check whether the cookie works or not.

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Cookie: session-x=hello-kookie"),  // example
```

Comment: I see..but will this still working if I put a script to auto login in an iframe and then user just have to click menus that exists in the remote site after login? because currently the scenario is just like I told you.